# Не получается посчитать максимальную, подряд идущую последовательность символов 'ABA'

Tags: python, строки

Допустим, есть последовательность символов 'ABAABABBBBBBBB'
Моя задача, найти максимальное количество подряд идущих последовательностей 'ABA'
В данном случае, ответ будет m = 2. Первые 6 символов. У меня прога печатает m=1. Почему-то каждый раз обнуляя переменную k. Не могу понять почему.

```
s = 'ABAABAABABBBB'
print (s)
k=0
m = 0
for i in range(2,len(s)):
    if s[i-2] == 'A' and s[i-1]=='B' and s[i]=='A':
        k=k+1
        m = max(k,m)
        i += 2
    else:
        k=0
print(m)
```

Comment: то, что вы изменили переменную `i`, не изменит её значение в следующем цикле. Надо переделать это в цикл `while`

Comment: тогда почему, если я пробую вывести переменные s[i-2],s[i-1],s[i],   когда выполняется условие. То у меня выводятся ABA,  потом снова ABA?  но k будет так и равно 1?

Comment: @newman допустим, будет 'ABAABABBBBBBBBABAABAABAABA'.  Самая длинная последовательность ABA = 4. Нам нужно пробегаться по строке/списку смотреть, если последовательность обрывается, то заносить в переменную m, а значение k обнулять, тем самым пытаясь найти самую длинную цепочку 'ABA. Не могу понять, как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример не очень корректный. Все же по нему получается 3 подстроки подряд. Плюс с константами немного подошиблись и с логикой. Ну и как было правильно замеченно, тут цикл **for** не подходит. Нужен **while**

Получилось как-то так

```
s = 'ABAABABBABABBBB'
print (s)
m = 0
k = 0
i = 2
while i < len(s):
    if s[i-2] == 'A' and s[i-1]=='B' and s[i]=='A':
        k += 1
        i += 3
    else:
        i += 1
        m = max(k, m)
        k = 0
   
print(m)
```

Т.е. логика примерно следующая: если условие соблюдается, то увеличиваем счетчик количества подстрок *k* в текущей последовательности.

Как только условие не сработало, то сравниваем число подсток в последовательности, с тем что уже было. Это функция **max** и переменная **m**. А счетик подстрок **k** обнуляем.

Ну и если условие выполняется, то переходим на три символа вперед. А если нет - то только на один

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как раз через while всё работает)